# Cosa significa "toppa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Un giorno di fuoco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Sospese di spaccare, posò un piede sulla **toppa** e si asciugava la fronte con un fazzoletto color ruggine.

La frase fa riferimento a un uomo che sta spaccando la legna. Il racconto è situato nelle Langhe durante l'infanzia dell'autore.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato del termine "toppa" in questo passaggio? L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari, ma le diverse accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [questo dizionario](https://books.google.it/books?id=x18VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=toppe%20taglio%20legna&source=bl&ots=27JhAdUGuf&sig=NrLVlSN1mSmKMSZZNvQbZdfCvRo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjykbic9OvcAhUB8YMKHf05Dj4Q6AEwE3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=toppe%20taglio%20legna&f=false) ho trovato:

> TACCHE, Copponi, Toppe, Falde più o men grosse che gli strumenti da
>   taglio spiccan dal legno che si recide, o si mette in opera.

E in [quest'altro dizionario Genovese-Italiano](http://doczz.it/doc/1089261/--zeneize.net):

> BUSCAGGE Toppe, Copponi, scheggie che gli strumenti da taglio fanno
>   cadere del legno che si atterra, o si mette in opera.

Il significato di toppa nel contesto da te citato è quello di una scheggia piuttosto grande che si è staccata dal tronco mentre veniva spaccato.